# Want to give blur effect of background image on sticker(image)

Tags: android

The sticker(image) on which I want blur effect of background image should be able to scale and it can move on entire background image. And the reflection on sticker should be as per its position on background image.

I have achieved scaling, rotation and motion of sticker by using OnTouchListener.

I have tired below code for blurring the sticker

```
private Bitmap makeBlurBitmap(float x, float y) {
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapBackImage);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitBackImage, (int)x, (int)y, null);
if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            blurBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitBackImage,(int)x , (int)y,
                    bitmapSticker.getWidth(), bitmapSticker.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(blurBitmapWithRenderscript(rs, blurBitmap),(int)x , (int)y , null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitSticker,(int)x , (int)y, null);
        }
 return bitSticker;
}


private static Bitmap blurBitmapWithRenderscript(RenderScript rs, Bitmap bitmap2) {
        //this will blur the bitmapOriginal with a radius of 25 and save it in bitmapOriginal
        final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap2); //use this constructor for best performance, because it uses USAGE_SHARED mode which reuses memory
        final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
        final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        // must be >0 and <= 25
        script.setRadius(25f);
        script.setInput(input);
        script.forEach(output);
        output.copyTo(bitmap2);
        return bitmap2;
    }
```

But this code doesn't return me what I need.

From above code I have achieved this:
[image]

And the result which I want to achive is:
[image]

Waiting for answer
Thanks.

Comment: Does the blur you want to achieve refer to the color of the sticker ?

Comment: No. It refers to color of background image

Comment: You should create a blurred version of the background image and use the alpha channel of the sticker as a mask to show this blurred version

Comment: Can you help me with the code?